# How to read timestamp csv file in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have csv file with timestamp. I have to read file using pyspark. but timestamp we don't know.
Please help me how to read it?

Example:

```
filename - projectno_without_data_20211030.csv
```

I have to read in this format without knowing the timestamp - `projectno_without_data_*.csv`

I am using below code-

```
df_read_file = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter", '|').options(header='true',quote='', escape='\"', inferSchema='false').load('/app/HTA/SrcFiles/inbound/metadata/projectno_without_data_*.csv')
```

Error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 178, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 134, in deco
    raise_from(converted)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/app/HTA/SrcFiles/inbound/metadata/projectno_without_data_*.csv;
```

Comment: Hello! An description of error that you get might be more useful to readers trying to help you out

Comment: @pri added error also

Comment: Do you want to load only the csv with the latest timestamp? or will there only be one csv in that folder anyway?

Comment: You can probably read the output of ls command and read that file. Or you could do a cp or mv of that file and then read the new file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df_read_file = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("delimiter", '|').options(header="true")
.load("/app/HTA/SrcFiles/inbound/metadata/projectno_without_data_*")
```

Can you try this?